# Refresh items list after adding an item

Tags: angular

Hello i am in the process of developing an application platform on angular, and i have a part where candidates can fill in their professional experiences!
The problem is that i can't update the list of experiences after adding an experience.

**Experience.component.ts**

```ts
export class ExperienceComponent implements OnInit {

  experience: Array<Experience> = [];
  
  constructor(
    private experienceService : ExperienceService,
    private modalService : NgbModal,
    private location : Location,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.experienceService.getExperiences().subscribe(
      result => this.experience = result
    )
  }

  /**
   * Add a new experience
   * @param addModel
   */
  addExperience(addModel : Experience){
    const add = this.modalService.open(AddExperienceComponent, { centered: true });
    add.componentInstance.selectedExperience = addModel;
  }

}
```

**Add-experience.component.ts**

```ts
export class AddExperienceComponent implements OnInit {

  addForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  experience;

  newExperience : Experience = {
    poste: '',
    entreprise: '',
    ville: '',
    dateDebut: '',
    dateFin: '',
    details: ''
  }
  constructor(
    public modal: NgbActiveModal,
    private experienceService: ExperienceService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setExperienceForm()
  }

  /**
   * Add a new experience
   */
   addNewExperience(){
    this.experienceService.addExperience(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        if (res) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Great',
          icon: 'success',
          html:
            'Your experience has been added !',
          confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Ok',
        });
        this.submitted = true;
        this.modal.close()
      }
    },
      err => Swal.fire({
        title: 'Oooops !',
        icon: 'error',
        html:
          'The end date must be greater than the start date',
        confirmButtonAriaLabel: 'Ok',
      }),
    )
    
  }

  get addExperienceData() { 
    return this.addForm.controls; 
  }

  private setExperienceForm() {    
    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      poste: [this.newExperience.poste, Validators.required],
      entreprise: [this.newExperience.entreprise, Validators.required],
      ville: [this.newExperience.ville, Validators.required],
      dateDebut: [this.newExperience.dateDebut, Validators.required],
      dateFin: [this.newExperience.dateFin, Validators.required],
      details: [this.newExperience.details, Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

To clarify, the add-experience component is used as a modal.

Here what it looks like my page : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdhoC.png)

Do you have any idea how to do it please ?

Thank you :)

**SOLUTION :**

Well after a day of looking for a solution, i've edited the function addExperience() in my Experience Component, it looks like this now :

```
addExperience(experienceModel : Experience){
    const ref = this.modalService.open(AddExperienceComponent, { centered: true });
    ref.componentInstance.selectedExperience = experienceModel;

    ref.result.then((yes) => {
      console.log(yes);
      this.setExperienceList();
    },
      (cancel) => {
        console.log(cancel);
      })
  }
```

And i've created a new function which contains the code inside ngOnInit(), and it looks like this :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setExperienceList();
  }

  /**
   * Get experiences
   */
  private setExperienceList() {
    this.experienceService.getExperiences().subscribe(x => {
      this.experience = x;
    })
```

Thank you for your help guys :)

Comment: Hey, of course i put it in a sharecode : https://sharemycode.io/c/87cc8b0

Answer (score 2):

You can emit added `experience` to parent component. In **Add-experience.component.ts** you should add one `EventEmitter`. On `EventEmitter` your parent component (**Experience.component.ts**) can "subscribe" and gets the added `experience`.

My words in code:

**Add-experience.component.ts**

```
@Output() newExperience: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
 ...

addNewExperience(){
 .... 
 this.newExperience.emit(this.addForm.value); // emit experience
}
```

**Experience.component.ts**

```
handleNewExperience(experience: any){ // This should be typed parameter
 this.experience.push(experience);
}
```

And of course you need to "subscribe" on emitter.

**Experience.component.ts**

```
<add-experience (newExperience)="handleNewExperience($event)"></add-experience>
```

Please keep it in mind this is only an idea. I don't know exactly how your code looks like. [Sharing data between child and parent directives and components](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs)

Comment: I understand and I thank you for your help! 
I just tried it but it doesn't work! 
The doc gives an example to send the name for example but here I want to send a data table

Comment: I looked at the doc and I see that this is the correct method but I don't know how to implement it! Could someone help me please?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to apply what they say in the doc ! Could you see my files and tell me how can i do please ?
Experience.component.ts : https://sharemycode.io/c/c2b01d1
Experience.component.html : https://sharemycode.io/c/53cb4b9
Add-Experience.component.ts : https://sharemycode.io/c/3583d2a
Add-Experience.component.html : https://sharemycode.io/c/3ede802

Comment: Hello i've created a minimal example in stackblitz if you can help me please ! 
Thank you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwp5js?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/add-experience/add-experience.component.ts

Comment: @Ayoub I will take a look on that today.

Answer (score 1):

So after I checked your code, you are using `Ngbmodal`. On that solution my idea is not good.

In **add-new-experience** component you need to `dismiss` your modal with created experience. In my example I sent the form value to the other component, but you should create an `experience` object.

```
 addNewExperience(experience) {
    // Create the object
    this.newExperience.company = this.addForm.get('company').value;
    this.newExperience.poste = this.addForm.get('poste').value;
    this.newExperience.city = this.addForm.get('city').value;
    this.newExperience.startDate = this.addForm.get('startDate').value;
    this.newExperience.endDate = this.addForm.get('endDate').value;
    this.newExperience.details = this.addForm.get('details').value;

    this.modal.close(this.newExperience);
}
```

In **experience** component you need to receive result from closed modal.

```
 addExperience() {
    const add = this.modalService
      .open(AddExperienceComponent, {
        centered: true
      })
      .result.then(
        (result: Experience) => {
         this.experience.push(result);
        },
        reason => {
          console.log(reason);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: The console.log(result) work so well ! but what does the commented line means ? I tried to do a push but it doesn't work

Comment: You can create an experience object from result, and you can push it to array. Your form and Experience class is two different thing.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i don't get it ! Could you explain me a bit more please ! :)

Comment: Sorry Bro i've passed my day looking how to do but it doesn't work ! 
I've tried your solution but it doesn't work either !

Comment: Please update your stackblitz  and I will check it!

Comment: I'll do it bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, i have similar workflow and i did this. At `Experience.component.ts` you subscribe to `getExperiences()` from `experienceService` i believe this returns a JSON or something from an APIs. then below that you can listen to any changes to that JSON, here's a simple code that might works for you.

`Experience.component.ts` inside constructor or `ngOnInit` add this code

```
this.experienceService.listen().subscribe((experiences: any) => {
      this.getListExperiences();
    });
```

then add this code outside constructor

```
getListExperiences(){
    this.experienceService.getExperiences().subscribe(
      result => this.experience = result
 )}
```

in `experienceService` you could use behaviour subject and observable.

```
  private _listeners = new Subject<any>();
  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return this._listeners.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: What about the listen() method ?

Comment: ah sorry about that, wait i'll add it to my answer

Comment: No problem ;) ;)

Comment: It doesn't work ! It's so complicated lol

Comment: lol np, u can use @tmsbrndz solution, this is similar but using `EventEmitter` instead of `Subject` and actually both do the same thing imo, also pretty simple, either way it's your choice

Comment: if you could create a minimal reproduce i can help u with this

Comment: @naoval, Yea I need more practice in RxJS.

Comment: actually i missed something wait, i'll edit my answer

Comment: I've tried but the list of experiences that already exists is no longer displayed

Comment: can you make a screenshot?

Comment: I would love to but i dont know how to add it in comments :P

Comment: Hey i've created a minimal example if you can help me please :) 
Thank you 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dwp5js?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/add-experience/add-experience.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oxl2un i couldnt make it work with local JSON go try changing the local JSON API to your live API

Comment: I've create a fake api for the test but i don't know why it doesn't work :P

Comment: can u edit your stackblitz with demo API?

Comment: It's done, in the services i've add a new url for the fake Api

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tbden this link doesnt updated